# express stop working - util is not defined

Tags: node.js, express

Had myself a little node/express app up and running. I haven't looked it for a out 3 months - now when I try to start the app I get the following error.

```
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
 Caught exception: ReferenceError: util is not defined
```

Anyone have any idea what spanner could have gotten into the works?
Any help much appreciated.

Express is at
"version": "2.5.0

Comment: Could you please show stacktrace and related code?

Comment: Seems to be mongoDB related, I'll get back with the code after I have done some more checking - thanks

Comment: Yes, it was because mongodb was down.

Answer (score 29):

You need to require util:

```
var util = require('util');
```

Maybe that happened in your Mongo code somewhere.